# jquery prevent animation queue build up

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have problem, if user clicks too fast on button, animation queue is keep piling up so it stops works properly. I would need behaviors, that when he clicks on button animation will always start current animation from beginning and forget about past animations in queue.

I tried `stop(true, true)` and `clearQueue()` adding to code below, but I'm doing this based on luck because don't understand jQuery well and didn't succeed with hours of trying.

```
var o, s, l;
e.animate = function(n, a, r, l, u) {
    o = u, s = [], i(n), t(".unddd").each(function(e, n) {
        Z.enqueue(function() {
            t(n).removeClass("unddd", 1, null, Z.dequeue)
        })
    }), Z.enqueue(function() {
        t(".unindicated").addClass("used_for_hand", o, null, Z.dequeue)
    }, t(".unindicated").size()), Z.enqueue(function() {
        t("#paybe").addClass("highlight"), Z.dequeue()
    }), Z.enqueue(function() {
    }), Z.startDequeue()
}, e.animateOut = function(e) {
    e ? Z.enqueue(function() {
        t(".status").hide(), t(".ble").addClass("discard", o, null, Z.dequeue)
    }, t(".ble").size()) : Z.enqueue(function() {
        t(".ble").not(".held").addClass("discard", o, null, Z.dequeue)
    }, t(".ble").not(".held").size()), Z.startDequeue()
}
```

Comment: HELP i dont know here to stop this animation from queueing!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean check "isRunning" and set it to true during your animate function, then set it to false when the animation is complete.

After that, just check isRunning == false before calling any animation methods. The animation will only run if it isnt already running.

Comment: This won't work, since i need start animation from beginning after each CLICK on button. Your solution suggesting not playing animation if first didn't end. Thats diffirent stuff.

Comment: Perhaps creating a function like the following which you call at the start of every click? 

$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".animatedElement" ).stop();
});

Comment: i feel we are almost there... if im switching game to gamesomthing animation is always complete so this is element that beign animated, so im using $(".game").stop(true,false);$(".game").clearQueue(); but it won't work yet, dunno why :/ im feeling we are closer now

Comment: HELP i dont know here to stop this animation from queueing!!

Answer (score 0):

i managed to work-around this, by disabling onclick after click and, enabling it after animation end